# L/100 km or km/L (л/100 км or км/л) which is used in Russia?

Tags: словоупотребление

In America we say the fuel economy of car as miles/gallon (miles per gallon). I know in some countries people use Liter/100 km, Some countries use km/Liter.

Which format do Russian people use, L/100 km or km/L? (л / 100 км or км / л)?

Comment: Usually L/100 km

Comment: Googled. Looks like l/100 km is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to Russian language and usage

Comment: @Tony the most common phrase for it would be "X литров на сотню" (kilometers are omitted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Russian people usually use L/100 km.